# Could not find class 'java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException'

Tags: android, sql-server, eclipse

**Description**
In Debug mode and using Eclipse when this code for Android process the line:
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
it's produce a errors in Logcat as such as:

**ERRORs**

```
Could not find class 'java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException', referenced from method com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.createArrayOf
02-09 08:15:46.325: W/dalvikvm(367): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 828 (Ljava/sql/SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;) in Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection;
02-09 08:15:46.325: D/dalvikvm(367): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0003
02-09 08:15:46.325: D/dalvikvm(367): VFY: dead code 0x0005-000e in Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection;.createArrayOf (Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;
02-09 08:15:46.385: I/dalvikvm(367): Failed resolving Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerNClob; interface 818 'Ljava/sql/NClob;'
02-09 08:15:46.385: W/dalvikvm(367): Link of class 'Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerNClob;' failed
02-09 08:15:46.395: E/dalvikvm(367): Could not find class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerNClob', referenced from method com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.createNClob
02-09 08:15:46.395: W/dalvikvm(367): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 563 (Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerNClob;) in Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection;
```

**Code**
This is only one part of this class:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectURL {

    public static void main() {

        // Create a variable for the connection string.
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.20:1433;" +
            "databaseName=BD;user=sa;password=pass1;integratedSecurity=true;";

        // Declare the JDBC objects.
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

            try {
                // Establish the connection.
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
....
```

Note
I have download Microsoft sqlserver jdbc 4.0 in a folder and in this project there is a Java build path with this route.

Answer (score 0):

[`java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/SQLFeatureNotSupportedException.html) is only available since API level 9.

I guess your are targeting a lower API level.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now I have used API > 8 and this error is not showed. However now there is a new error: 01-29 11:54:20.387: E/dalvikvm(1137): Could not find class 'javax.sql.XAConnection', referenced from method com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.poolCloseEventNotify
01-29 11:54:20.387: W/dalvikvm(1137): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 913 (Ljavax/sql/XAConnection;) in Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection;

Comment: If it solve the issue with the question please accept (and upvote if it help). Regarding XAConnection : this class is NOT part of the Android API. I guess you need it because your transaction manager is configured to work with more than one database (or external resource). If you really need that feature: you will have to find another version of the driver not relying on 'javax.sql.XAConnection'. If you only have one DB, this class shouldn't be required, so I suggest you to investigate more deeply for possible configuration issues with your driver.

Comment: Excuse me, when you wrote "please accept..." do you refer to press "Yes" button below, where is indicated "Was this post...?". In this case I accepted it. So, in reference to this issue, I only have a remote database in a external machine but this class is required, so it seems. Moreover I saw a other similar issue with this error and it indicate install JEE's, so I have to do that and I have been able to add import javax.sql.*; but the problem persist.